# iOS 14, can Airplane Mode be automated without confirmation?

Tags: shortcuts-app

Apple's website claims that Wifi is one category of shortcuts which can be run without requiring confirmation of the user.  But this does not seem to be the case for me, in iOS 14.

I want to enable Airplane mode any time I'm connected to my home wifi network, to help with battery life (and I'm nearly always at home).  But every time the automation runs, I'm required to manually confirm that I want to run it, which defeats the purpose.

Is there a way to do this?  Is this an iOS 14 limitation that has been lifted in later versions?